# dotnet build - working, dotnet publish - not working

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I try publish ASP .NET Core2 app.

App is work in visual studio 2017

**dotnet build -c Release** completed without error

**dotnet publish -c Release**

Has error

*Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Hangfire.MemoryStorage'*

But **Hangfire.MemoryStorage** is **_Libs\Hangfire.MemoryStorage.dll** not a package

Answer (score 2):

build compiles all your .cs files mainly
publish also compiles all your view files into a single .dll file. So it validates your views as well. 
So, If you have an error only in the publish and not in the build, there most probably must be a bug somewhere in your views. Even if the app worked in visual studio, there might be a run time issue somewhere if the bug is in a view.

Regarding the Hangfire.MemoryStorage library. The last update was three months ago. There have also been past issues with this library related to the code not updated for the latest version of .net core. So, I don't think he has released the stable version for .net core 2.0 yet (assuming you have the latest version of the app installed).